# "Trying to get property of non-object" - from a CURL response

Tags: curl, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

so i get the json api response from a remote resource via CURL like this:

```
$curly = json_decode($output, true);
```

and then i pass it to the view building function like this:

```
return View::make('assman.index', $curly);
```

and then when i try to access a $curly attribute in the blade view like this:

```
... {{ $asses[0]->url }} ...
```

my happy ending looks like:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

so um.. I just needed to typecast the curl response:

```
$curly = (array)json_decode($output);
```

dammit.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do (you gave very limited into), you may want to use $curly = `json_decode($output, true);` instead. That way, the results are arrays within arrays, not objects within arrays. In that case, you want to get the data like this: `$curly['subobject']['subsubobject']`

Comment: I know, i initially went with that. but.. you know.. arrows->cool, brackets['notCool']